# Office365 OAuth - Token via CURL

Tags: php, azure, curl, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to connect to the Azure platform to grab a response, mainly to get the token for use when accessing an office365 mailbox

The following is what i'm using, but I always get a NULL response

What other CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS need to be included, or what else needs to be changed.

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => "https://login.microsoftonline.com/".$tennantid."/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'client_id='.$appid.'&response_type=token&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read&redirect_uri='.$uri,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      ),
    ));
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $response_decode = json_decode($response);
var_dump($response_decode);
    curl_close($curl);
```

I currently get the token back ok when I use the following method

```
  $params = array ('client_id' =>$appid,
  'redirect_uri' =>$uri,
  'response_type' =>'token',
   'response_mode' =>'form_post',
  'scope' =>'https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read',
  'state' =>$_SESSION['state']);
  header ('Location: '.$login_url.'?'.http_build_query ($params));
```

Which works fine.

But I need to do CURL method as I need this running background cron job task

What do I seem to be missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The curl code is dealing with an SSL connection yet there are no options at all to negotiate certificates and there is no attempt to debug the connection - have you printed out the errors? Have you tried using verbose mode for curl?

Comment: You are trying to use an interactive authentication endpoint from non-interactive code. That won't work. You need to use a different authentication flow like Client Credentials flow.

Answer (score 0):

A link to the API documentation may have helped.  Without that I cannot help much.  Just one obvious thing.

You are using `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

You are not encoding the data.  From MDN:

> application/x-www-form-urlencoded: the keys and values are encoded in
> key-value tuples separated by '&', with a '=' between the key and the
> value. Non-alphanumeric characters in both keys and values are **percent
> encoded**: this is the reason why this type is not suitable to use with
> binary data (use multipart/form-data instead)

Source: [MDN Post data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST)

---

This would mean your request data should look like this:

```
client_id%3D1234%26response_type%3Dtoken%26scope%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FUser.Read%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%3Aexample.com
```

Try this:

```
$post = urlencode('client_id='.$appid.'&response_type=token&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read&redirect_uri=http:example.com');
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $ post,
```

Comment: This encoding will not work - it encodes the = and & characters as well so there is no separation between keys and values. A correctly encoded POST request should look  like
client_id=1234&response_type=token&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FUser.Read&redirect_uri=http%3Aexample.com